# Link between marginal effects of probit estimation and proportions in sample

Tags: interpretation, probit

Suppose you are estimating a model with a binary dependent variable $Y_i$ and where the explanatory variables are a randomly assigned binary treatment $D_i$ and a vector of covariates. My understanding is that the marginal effect of $D_i$ is interpreted as the probability of $Y_i$ being 1 if $D_i=1$, holding other covariates constant (correct me if I'm mistaken).

So my question is whether you can interpret this change of *probability* for the treated *unit* as an impact on the proportions (or distribution) of $Y_i$ in the *sample*. The variable of interest is a systemic -not individual- characteristic, so it is interesting to draw a conclusion for the effect of the treatment on a *group* of observations.

For example, suppose $Y_i$ is a dummy indicating whether merchant $i$ sells illegal products in his store. Merchants are grouped in small fairs. Suppose also that $D_i$ is a treatment intended to curb this behavior, randomly assigned at the fair level. If you find that the marginal effect of $D$ is $-0.1$, that means that the probability that a treated merchant sells illegal merchandise is, on average, 10 percentage points less than non-treated ones. But can you say that the proportion of merchants that sell illegal products in treated fairs is 10 p.p. less than in non-treated fairs?